# SQL Sub Query issue in Spark

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

**Hi, I have a SQL query as below. When I run the same query in PostgreSQL query tool, it's working fine. But when I try it in Spark SQL, its showing the following error in spark logs**

```
val SQLDF = spark.sqlContext.sql("""
select m.v_number, o.u_id, r_number, v_name, p.pr_name
from
    PG_DF_VHM m,
    OBU_VIN_DF o,
    PROJ_NAME_DF p
where
    m.v_number = o.v_number
    and p.pr_id in (
        select pr_id
        from PROJ_USER_DF
        where
            user_id in (
                select user_id
                from PG_MAP_DF
                where
                    project_user_id in (
                        select project_user_id
                        from PROJ_USER_DF u
                        where
                            u.user_id = o.created_by
                    )
                    and user_role_id = 3
                limit 1
            )
    )
""")
```

```
ERROR ApplicationMaster: User class threw exception: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`o.created_by`' given input columns:24/03/11 06:46:51 

ERROR ApplicationMaster: User class threw exception: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: 
cannot resolve '`o.created_by`' 
given input columns: [
u.project_id, 
u.created_by, 
u.user_id, 
u.project_user_id, 
u.updated_timestamp, 
u.is_deleted, 
u.updated_by, 
u.created_timestamp
]; line 1 pos 33
```

Comment: Exception is telling you don't have `created_by` column in `OBU_VIN_DF` table. Please check once.. Better try to use `CTE` for better readability.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, but in error its showing only PROJ_USER_DF table columns only. in  OBU_VIN_DF o table created_by column is available.

Comment: you should specify the spark version used at a minimum (3.4+ have better support for correlated subqueries), reproducable cases are also better.  That said, try moving u.user_id = o.created_by to the top level PROJ_USER_DF query, correlated subqueries are implemented as joins so you could also try to re-write it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from PG_DF_VHM m,
OBU_VIN_DF o,
PROJ_NAME_DF p is wrong. Here use some common column to join . for eg id is common
from PG_DF_VHM m join OBU_VIN_DF o on m.id=o.id join PROJ_NAME_DF p on m.id =p.id

Something like that

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).